# Passing Rulesets into Mixins not working

Tags: css, less

I copied the following text from the website: http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature and SimpleLESS is giving me an error on the line that I copied it to. Did they remove the ruleset capabilities?

Here is what I copied:

```
// declare detached ruleset
@detached-ruleset: { background: red; };

// use detached ruleset
.top {
    @detached-ruleset(); 
}
```

I wanted to test to see if I can name the variable "detached-ruleset" to whatever I want so that I can use more than one, but the code from the less website doesn't even work. Any one know whats going on?

Comment: It's just SimpleLESS that is vastly outdated. Consider using more up-to-date tools.

Comment: Voting to close (though this is not a typo error and can be reproduced using an older version compiler) because the problem is due to usage of a older compiler version.

Comment: Well thank you for helping me understand what was wrong with what i thought was the code. The tutorial that I watched said to use simpless. I didn't realize it wasn't up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply due to SimpleLESS not being updated for almost 3 years, as stated by Seven-phases-max in the comment.

In all honesty, your best bet is to actually use Less's own compiler which will of course be the most up to date option.

All the information can be found in the [Less Documentation Here](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage)